# General solutions of Trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

Find the general solution of:

$$\sin^3 \theta - \sin \theta = 0$$

Working out: (Factorise out)

$$\sin \theta (\sin^2 \theta - 1)  = 0$$

Solve for $\sin \theta$ and $\sin^2 \theta - 1$:

For $\sin \theta = 0$

$$\sin \theta = 0$$

$$\therefore \theta = 0$$

$$\therefore \theta = n \pi$$

For  $\sin^2 \theta - 1 = 0$:

$$\sin^2 \theta - 1 = 0$$

$$\sin^2 \theta = 1$$

$$\sin \theta = \pm1$$

$$\theta = - \pi/2, \pi/2$$

$$\therefore \theta = n\pi + (-1)^n(\pm\pi/2)$$

So i get the two solutions as:

$$\theta = n\pi\text{ and }\theta = n\pi + (-1)^n(\pm\pi/2)$$

However a complication occurs because wolframalpha says otherwise, help would be greatly appreciated.

[Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%5E3+%28theta%29+-+sin+%28theta%29+%3D+0)

Comment: Hint: $sin^2\theta - 1 = - cos^2\theta$

Comment: I would write $n\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}$ for the $\sin^2\theta=1$ case. Or maybe $2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. You are entioning everybody twice. Which is not wrong, but it is not optimal.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can someone explain to me why my one is wrong though?

Comment: @Lost Why would I make it equal to $-\cos^2 \theta$?, why not just use what's provided?

Comment: Take $n=0$, and the $+$. We get $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Take $n=1$, and the $+$. We get $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Right, but stuttery. You should also not talk about $2$ solutions, it is $2$ (or $3$, depends how one counts) **families** of solutions.

Comment: Because then you get $-cos^2\theta=0$ which would be easier to solve, and thus you'd have been able to compare with the answer you got. The way you did was fine, but it's easier to trip up in my opinion.

Comment: @MATHSUSER: I think I have explained. And it is not *wrong*, but your expression mentions each of the solutions of $\sin^2\theta=1$ twice.

Comment: @Lost But i still get $\pi/2$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas - but that's because of the square root. But can't I just write them separately if that's the case like this?

$n\pi + (-1)^n (\pi/2)$ and $n\pi + (-1)^n (-\pi/2)$

Comment: Precisely - that is correct.  As André says, you aren't wrong, but could write the solution better.  Changing the equation in terms of cosine hopefully can help you eliminate any confusion relating to $\pm 1$

Comment: Oh okay thank you, so I am not wrong, but the only problem is me writing the $\pm 1$. I am just confused at how wolframalpha reaches that conclusion that is all.

Comment: This is OK, and mentions everybody only once. There are many ways one can describe the solutions. I would call $n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$, or the equivalent $(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ simpler-looking than your version. However, your revised version is correct, and non-repetitive.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Alright thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\cos^2\theta=0$ is definitely the easiest as it implies and is impled by $\displaystyle\cos\theta=0\implies \theta$ is  odd multiple of $\displaystyle \frac\pi2$

Otherwise using [Double-Angle Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/search/?query=double%20angle&x=-847&y=-137),

$\displaystyle\sin^2\theta=\sin^2\alpha\iff \cos^2\theta=\cos^2\alpha$
$\displaystyle\iff\tan^2\theta=\tan^2\alpha$
$\displaystyle\iff\cos2\theta=\cos2\alpha$

$\displaystyle\implies 2\theta=2n\pi\pm2\alpha $ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 1):

When you write the solution for $$\ (\sin^2 \theta - 1)  = 0$$ your answer is correct but you did not notice that what you wrote is exactly an odd multiple of $\displaystyle \frac\pi2$ as mentioned by lab bhattacharjee.